# Accessing class methods of module

Tags: ruby, module

I try to include/extend a module A into a module B which in turn gets included into a class C. Then I want to invoke a class method named cm of A but I don't know how.

```
module A
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cm
      puts "cm"
    end
  end
end

module B
 include A
end

class C
 extend B
end

c = C.new
c.cm # -> does not work
C.cm # -> does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

You can really simplify this syntax with the augmentations plug-in:

https://github.com/henrik/augmentations

or the gem based on it:

https://github.com/chemica/augmentations-gem

Use:

```
class User 
  augment MyModule
end
```

with modules like

```
module MyModule
  augmentation do


    def self.a_class_method
      # …
    end

    def an_instance_method
      # …
    end

  end
end
```

The plug-in itself is tiny, just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

When including modules, you do this:

```
module A
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.include ClassMethods
    puts :included
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cm
      puts :cm
    end
  end
end

module B
 include A
end

class C
 include B
end

c = C.new
c.cm
```

Similarly when extending classes, you do this:

```
module X
  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cm
      puts :cm
    end
  end
end

module Y
  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.extend X
  end
end

class Z
 extend Y
end

Z.cm
```

See 
[Include vs Extend in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)